# I want to create .a file i.e. iOS SDK from multiple class but when I build one .m file build in .a only one class is available

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I want to create .a file i.e. iOS SDK from multiple class but when I build the project only one .m file build in .a only one class is available. So please help with the same.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create static library?

Comment: What have you trie so far? How are you doing it now?

Comment: @BharatModi right static library

Comment: @Andrej I have followed the steps to create static library and after that I have include other classes but when I including library to other project other classes are not found .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating iOS Static library then you can add as many as classes you want, just make sure you add the classes to the Compile Sources under Target's Build Phases which you want to make header files visible. When you build the library you will able to see the header files of all classes only and that is one of the reason we create the library to hide the implementation part.

[image]

You can get more info about how to create static library on below pages.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/creating-static-library-in-ios-app-development/